# Refer to column of a data frame that is being defined

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe in pandas *and directly use one of the generated columns* to assign a new column to the same df.
As a simplified example, I tried to multiply a column of a df using assign:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]] , columns = ['col1', 'col2'])\
.assign(col3 = 2 * col2)
```

but then I get an error `NameError: name 'col2' is not defined`.

Using R/dplyr, I would be able to do this in a pipe using

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:3], col2 = 1:3) %>% mutate(col3 = 2 * col2)
```

Also, in a general sense, pipe notation in R/dplyr allows the usage of the "." to refer to the data forwarded by the pipe.

Is there a way to refer to the columns just created (or to the data that goes into the assign statement), thus doing the same thing in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function, more information in [Assigning New Columns in Method Chains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#dsintro-chained-assignment):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]] , columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
       .assign(col3 = lambda x: 2 * x.col2))
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     1     2
1    B     2     4
2    C     3     6
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a package [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) to port `dplyr` and family to python. Now you can do it with (almost) the same syntax as you do it in R:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, LETTERS, mutate
>>> tibble(col1=LETTERS[:3], col2=f[1:3]) >> mutate(col3=2*f.col2)
      col1    col2    col3
  <object> <int64> <int64>
0        A       1       2
1        B       2       4
2        C       3       6
```